# Finding date of next Thursday in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm trying to make a app which includes telling the time of next Thursday. App crashes every time i open that class.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_authorised);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            nextThursday();
        }
    });

}

void nextThursday(){
    String nextThursday = getNext(DayOfWeek.THURSDAY).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM, dd yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH));
    nextThurs.setText(nextThursday);
}

public static LocalDate getNext(DayOfWeek dayOfWeek) {
    // get the reference day for the word "next" (that is the current day)
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
    // start with tomorrow
    LocalDate next = today.plusDays(1);

    // as long as the desired day of week is not reached
    while (next.getDayOfWeek() != dayOfWeek) {
        // add one day and try again
        next = next.plusDays(1);
    }

    // then return the result
    return next;
}
```

}

Is anyone able to help?

Comment: Do you have to use Joda or can you switch to `java.time`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question include the error message / stack trace. Make sure the code is a [mcve]. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

This answer uses `java.time`, which is the datetime API to be used since the Joda Time project stopped further development.

It basically uses an algorithm that may be realizable in Joda Time, too, but I don't know exactly if and how, so I show you a way in `java.time`.

Define a method that returns the date of the next given day of week:

```
public static LocalDate getNext(DayOfWeek dayOfWeek) {
    // get the reference day for the word "next" (that is the current day)
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
    // start with tomorrow
    LocalDate next = today.plusDays(1);

    // as long as the desired day of week is not reached
    while (next.getDayOfWeek() != dayOfWeek) {
        // add one day and try again
        next = next.plusDays(1);
    }

    // then return the result
    return next;
}
```

and use it in a `main()` just to print it out:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Next Thursday is " + 
            getNext(DayOfWeek.THURSDAY)
                .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM, dd yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)));
}
```

which results in the output when executed Friday, 15th of May 2020:

```
Next Thursday is May, 21 2020
```

Of course, the format is just an example and can easily be adjusted according to your needs.

Comment: Getting two errors. "Operator '!=' cannot be applied to 'int', 'java.time.DayOfWeek' "and "cannot resolve method format(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter"

Comment: @Adventune Seems like the classes are mixed up, have you imported both libraries, Joda and `java.time`? Maybe use qualifications, like `java.time.DayOfWeek` and `java.time.LocalDate`...

Comment: Oh right. Forgot to change it from joda to java. I'll check it´f it works now

Comment: @Adventune there is just a little disadvantage of using `java.time` in Android: it is natively supported from Android 26 on, for the support of lower API versions, you will have to use a [backport](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP)...

Comment: App still crashes. I updated the code on the question

Comment: Have to run with logcat can't do it right now. I'll get back to it when i have time

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple using a predefined `TemporalAdjuster`:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now()
    .with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.THURSDAY));
```

This is natively supported since Java 8 or Android API level 26. To target previous API levels, use the [ThreeTen Android Backport](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

Joda Time is in maintenance mode, and they're suggesting that you use `java.time` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Deleted all code in that activity. Still crashed. Error was not in the code. Something else got messed up instead.